# how to change read unknown files by vb

Tags: vb.net, null, notepad++

Hope all is well,dis is Mohammad. i have a file which is unknown but me really think it is kind of text file. me has found it in the source of one program and when me want to open it by notepad ++ me see null Soh and other characters which has no mean and in other languages.me really must open it by vb .Is there any one to help me?please help me if you can..me really need to no what is it in dis source
          و<     گش¼        €        ً?         و<      8@                 ً?         8@      8@                  ً?         8@      @@                  ً?         H@      @@                 ً?         H@     گش¼        €        ً?         و<      :@                 ً?         8@      :@                  ً?         و<      <@                 ً?           8@      <@                  ً?
         و<      >@                 ً?         8@      >@                  ً?         و<      @@                 ً?
         8@      ?@                  ً?        €@@      >@                  ً?         8@      =@                  ً?        €@@      <@                  ً?         8@      ;@                  ً?        €@@      9@                  ً?         8@      9@                  ً?        ?@      7@                  ً?         @@      @@                  ً?

Comment: it's probably some sort of binary format. What's the file extension? Have you googled it?

Comment: i can send you a file. it is in the source of the one file and i use notepad++ to opening.if you give me your email i can send you a file.

Comment: No. That's not how this site works anyway - the idea is for everyone to be able to help together. You've already given a sample of the data. I asked you about the file extension, you can answer that without sending the whole file. Anyway, why would I accept a file from a stranger? How do I know it's not got a virus in it (I'm not saying you would do that deliberately, but I still wouldn't trust it, since you don't know what it is either).

Comment: yes. you are right.I respect to your idea. this file has no extension. what is your idea? what shoud i do?

Comment: don't you have any idea where this file came from? Who created it, and why? Do you know if it was generated by a specific piece of software?

Comment: i have gotten it from plaxis software which is one of the civil engineering software. it is original and it may show the points.

Comment: it's unlikely you can read it then without understanding Plaxis' file format. If you have their software you could try decompiling it with dotPeek or a similar tool, to see if you can understand the code which generates the files. The results of this sort of process are variable though, and its legality is questionable when doing it on commercial software. If you have a support contract with Plaxis they may have some documentation on the file format, or you could ask them for information on it. But since it's a proprietary commercial product they may not wish to tell you.

Comment: Thank you very much. i cannot understand this file yet.becace dot peek cannot read this software format .

Comment: dotpeek would be for reading the compiled code of the Plaxis application, not for reading this specific file. From reading the code you might be able to work out how the file is generated and therefore understand the format.

Comment: Thank you very much..but when i want to use dotpeek for reading plaxis software..i see that dotpeek cannot support this software and all of files in this software.why??

Comment: how do you know? Did you try it? Or find some documentation? There are other decompilers available, not just that one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an already compiled or coded file. 
You may use .dotpeek decompiler to get more information if you're sure it's something related with VB.

Best luck!

Comment: i use vb because before opening this file this file must be identified by vb in one folder . actually i want to going into source files and changing them and finally closing files just by vb.